# need to select a number of characters using regex

Tags: regex

I have a sentence like:

```
"Reentry BUY AUDUSD @ 0.90209 "
```

I want to extract "AUDUSD" using regex.

```
(.*?)@
```

I want to select 7 characters from the left of "@" so I can extract "AUDUSD".

Comment: You mean `\w+(?=\s*@)`? `[A-Z]+(?= *@)`? `([A-Z]+) *@`?

Answer (score 0):

The `(.*?)@` pattern matches and captures into Group 1 any zero or more characters other than line break chars, as few as possible, *starting with the leftmost match*, so you literall start matching from the start of the line where the `@` char is.

You need to use a more precise pattern:

```
\w+(?=\s*@)
[A-Z]+(?=\s*@)
([A-Z]+) @
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dvgU3t/1). In the first two examples, the value you need lands in the whole match, in the third one, the value is captured in Group 1.

**Details**

- `\w+(?=\s*@)` - 1+ letters/digits/underscores followed with 0+ whitespaces and `@`
- `[A-Z]+(?=\s*@)` - 1+ uppercase ASCII letters followed with 0+ whitespaces and `@`
- `([A-Z]+) @`  - capturing group 1 matching 1+ uppercase ASCII letters, then a space and `@` are matched (but not captured).